# How to access a computed property from a method in a Single File Component with Vue.js

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component, computed-properties

I have a normal *single file component* which has both a **computed property** and some **methods**:

```
<template>...</template>
<script>
...
export default {
    props: ['matches'],
    data: function() {...}  // No problem with these

    computed: {
        formattedMatches: function () {
            let formatted = [];
            this.matches.forEach(function($match, $i, $arr) {
                formatted[$i] = $match[0];
            };
        });
        return formatted;
    }
    ...

    methods: {
        getData: function() {
            return this.formattedMatches();
        },
        ...
    }
}
<script>
```

When I try to access `this.formattedMatches()` **from the method**, I get a `[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: this.formattedMatches is not a function"`
.

What is the correct way to achieve what I want?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: computed **property**  is one property, not one method, so change `this.formattedMatches()` to `this.formattedMatches`.

Comment: Thanks, that solved the problem, you're right

Answer (score 103, accepted):

You can access computed properties like a `property`, not like a `method`:

```
// correct    
console.log(this.myProperty);

// wrong    
console.log(this.myProperty());
```

Note: If you treat it as a method with paracentesis `()` it shall throw an error like this `Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: this.myProperty is not a function"`.

Comment: dang how to know that just property is required tried always as method, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have given

```
isWeb: function () {
        return isWebOnly;
      }
```

in computed properties.

Now I HAVE TO USE isWeb() in the methods section

```
isQuickViewEnabled (
        { userData }: {userData: AlgoliaUserData[] | undefined }): boolean {
        if (Array.isArray(userData)) {
          const quickViewEnabled = userData[0]?.quick_view_enabled;
          return this.**isWeb** && quickViewEnabled;
        }
        return false;
      },
```

But its giving Property 'isWeb' does not exist on type 'CombinedVueInstance<Vue, unknown, unknown, unknown, Readonly<{ product: any; position: number; results: any; cornerFlagsRules: CornerFlags[]; }>>'.